# Is non-normalized bone weight possible?

Tags: unity, vertex-weights

I wand to model a 3D UI container that resize along the X and Y axes, with some border parts whose size remain constant (i.e. the 3D equivalent of the 2D 9-patch images). My target is Unity, which seems to only support bone animations.

In Blender, I made an armature with 2 disconnected bones, one for each axis X and Y. They are disconnected so I can move them freely on each X and Y axes. Then I assigned halves of my 3D model to each bone, horizontally and vertically. I was hoping that it would work as intended but I have a problem : the part of my 3D model which should have been translated by the 2 bones at the same time on X and Y are only influenced at 50% by each bone.

[image]
[image]

I was hoping this part to be influenced by 100% of each bone in an additive fashion. It seems that there is an automatic normalization of the bones weights on each vertex. Is there a way to avoid this normalization in Blender?

Alternatively, is there another animation technique in Blender that allow for additive deformation whilst being exportable as bone-based animation?

Answer (score 1):

Instead using bones, try to use hooks. It hasn't normalization at all.
[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It works inside Blender, however it doesn't export as a bone-based animation in Unity.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to solve the problem using a workaround, therefore I am not going to tag it as the valid answer because it does not answer the question.

My solution is to use 3 bones, one for each moving part.

[image]
[image]